# Do javascript functions need to be declared in the reverse order?

Tags: javascript, function

Elaboration: If I would have, for example the following code:

```
//Javascript example
var alice = function() {
    var value = bob() + 1;
    console.log value
}
var bob = function() {
    var value = 1;
    return value;
}

//Running function A
alice()
```

Would I have to declare function B first, because I am calling it in function A without reaching function B yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you have a function declaration, then it will be hoisted and order doesn't matter (although putting functions in an order so that a function call doesn't appear before the function being called is good practice).

If you have function **expressions** (as you do in your example), then you need to have the functions created before they are **called**, noting that in this example none of them are called before the line `alice()` so only that line needs to be after the functions and the order of the functions themselves doesn't matter. (But the best practise principles described above hold).

Answer (score 0):

No, because the Javascript interpreter will recognize the functions declared after and link them appropriately to the line in question.

Comment: Would it make any difference if I call function alice() at the beginning of the program? As in, before I define them? Would that make it not worK?

Comment: @user3367792 No, you can't call them before the assignment occurs when using function expressions (`var ... = function ...;`). The declared variable will be available before hand, but not yet with the `function` as its value.

Answer (score 0):

The only limitation is the definition of every function before utilization

Comment: No.  Function declaration statements are hoisted.

Comment: @SLaks - There are no function declaration statements in the question.